# Computer having multiple hardware related power issues

Tags: windows-10, boot, power-supply, bsod, sleep

Over the past few months, my computer has been experiencing multiple hardware related power issues, such as:

- Being unable to automatically go into sleep mode
- DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSOD
- Powering on but not properly booting, ie computer fans run at full speed but peripherals do not turn on

The inability to go into sleep mode has persisted ever since errors started occurring, and I was only able to make it work for one full day by removing powercfg privileges from multiple devices and programs.
The DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSOD occurred twice daily for 3 days a couple of months ago, but hasn't happened since.
The biggest issue is with my computer not booting. This has only happened about 3 times ever since the power issues started showing up, and by just restarting the computer it would then boot up normally. However earlier today, the error occurred 4 times in a row.

I'm certain this is a hardware issue, but am unsure which part I should replace. Does this sound like a PSU, Ram card, or Motherboard type of issue?

Comment: Get the Hardware Diagnostic App from the computer manufacturer and run a full set of diagnostics. That will usually help determine hardware issues. Also get the Driver Update app and update all drivers including BIOS.

Comment: It could be any or all of those devices.  You should be able to make a powercfg query to determine which device is preventing the machine from going into sleep mode.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you：https://thegeekpage.com/fix-windows-10-sleep-mode-not-working-solved/